# BLE device disconnect, then two opposite exception BleAlreadyConnectedException vs BleDisconnectedException

Tags: android, rxandroidble

I'm working on a DFU OTA (device firmware update on the air).

To do it, I must connect the device, then send a command to order the device to switch to bootloader mode. After this command the device reboot, thus connection is lost. Just after this state if I try to reconnect with

```
rxBledevice
?.establishConnection(false)
?.subscribe({/**/},{/**/})
```

raise the error BleAlreadyConnectedException

Then, if I send any command to the device, for example with

```
rxBleConnection
?.writeCharacteristic(UUID, ba)
?.subscribe({/**/},{/**/})
```

raise the error, BleDisconnectedException.

I try to Dispose the connection observer but nothing changed. The only way (not acceptable) is to restart the app after the BleDevice reboot and disconnect.

If it can help, I also got these logs:

```
E/BLE: write control OTA failed : com.polidea.rxandroidble2.exceptions.BleGattCallbackTimeoutException: GATT exception from MAC address 00:0B:57:4C:6C:9B, with type BleGattOperation{description='CHARACTERISTIC_WRITE'}
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=22 clientIf=7 device=00:0B:57:4C:6C:XX
E/BLE: error connection BLE Disconnected from 00:0B:57:4C:6C:9B with status 22 (UNKNOWN)
```

Do you have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You're probably not disposing the previous `RxBleConnection` subscription but it cannot be confirmed as you have not shown any relevant code.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I have a similar problem where I connect then the peripheral throws an GATT_ERROR and the error leg of my connection is executed. I can't figure out how to recover from this gracefully.